# Open pages with ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I want to open a page with ajax, and ajax to show the link in the browser url.  Of course, the page does not reload the whole page, only the content. 
Here is my code., but I keep on having an error **"Notice: Undefined index: rel in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\html5-history-api\menu1.php on line 2"**

I'd like this error to go away...

**header.php :**

```
<br>Header Content from header.php</br></br>
<style>
#menu{font-size:20px;}
#content{font-size:30px;}
</style>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault(); 
        /*  
        if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link. 
        */

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
        $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }});

        //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
});

/* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    }});
});
</script>
<div id='menu'>
    <a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/www/html5-history-api/menu1.php'>menu1</a> | 
    <a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/www/html5-history-api/menu2.php'>menu2</a> | 
    <a rel='tab' href='http://localhost/www/html5-history-api/menu3.php'>menu3</a>
</div>
```

And menu1.php (menu2 and 3 are the same as 1)

```
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='content'>";
}
?>
menu1 content in menu1.php
<?php 
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
    echo "</div>";
    include 'footer.php';
}?>
```

So yeah, the code works, but I don't like having an error in my code and I don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the method of the AJAX call. Are you sure you're sending a GET call instead of POST? If you're sending POST, $_GET will not have 'rel' index set.

Try `$.ajax({ type: "GET", ...`

Comment: you should use isset() before attempting to compare get parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying updating it from:

```
if($_GET['rel']!='tab'){
```

To this:

```
if(isset($_GET['rel']) ? $_GET['rel']!='tab')){
```

See if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, you don't have an array index defined. your code should be

```
if (isset($_GET['rel']) && ($_GET['rel'] != 'tab')) {
```